# Experiencing (ARC) Semantic Issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

All day, I have been cleaning up an old project of mine.
I have a lot of needless features that I want to get rid of to avoid the app from getting to cramped (including an intro screen that I would like to redesign).

Anyways, I've created a new project and I've been transferring over bits of code, piece by piece to keep everything clean. 
All of the code seems to be in the same place as my previous project, however, **I am now receiving numerous *Semantic Issue* (occasional *ARC* Semantic Issue) errors upon building the app.**

[image]

Is there any stupid mistake I am making that someone else has encountered themselves? Or am I doing something frantically wrong. Newbie here, I apologize in advance.

If anyone is willing to take a deeper look into the issue, I'd be happy to send the project. :)

Comment: please attach at least the full log - that one is cut off after 1/2 a sentence :(

Comment: It looks like you haven't imported CoreData into your app delegate or prefix file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to have imported the Core Data headers into your app delegate.

`#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>`